# how to get the base url using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

My app is going to work in multiple env, in which i need to get the common value (base url for my app) to work across..

from my window location how to i get certain part from the start..

example :

```
    http://xxxxx.yyyy.xxxxx.com:14567/yx/someother/foldername/index.html
```

how can i get only:

```
http://xxxxx.yyyy.xxxxx.com:14567/yx/
```

my try :

```
var base = \w([yx]/)
```

the base only select `yx/` how to get the value in front of this?

this part..

thanks in advance..

Comment: When you say "base url", do you mean a URL you've specified with the `<base>` element in your HTML?

Comment: no, the path common for all environments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If 'someother' is known to be the root of your site, then replace

```
    \w([yx]/)
```

with

```
    (.*\/)someother\/
```

(note that the / characters are escaped here) which gives a first match of:

```
   http://xxxxx.yyyy.xxxxx.com:14567/yx/
```

However, a regular expression may not be the best way of doing this; see if there's any way you can pass the base URL in by another manner, for example from the code running behind the page.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind disregarding the trailing slash, you can do it without a regex:

```
var url = 'http://xxxxx.yyyy.xxxxx.com:14567/yx/someother/foldername/index.html';

url.split('/', 4).join('/');
//-> "http://xxxxx.yyyy.xxxxx.com:14567/yx"
```

If you want the trailing slash, it's easy to append with `+ '/'`.

Comment: This doesn't cater for situations where it's running from the root of the site, or under two or more subfolders.

Comment: @AdrianWragg what?  Your comment makes no sense.  Can you give me a real example of where your answer would succeed where my own would fail?

Comment: http://www.sample.com/someother/foldername/index.html, or http://www.sample.com/yx/zy/someother/foldername/index.html

Comment: @AdrianWragg: right, I see what you're saying... but this isn't the case for the OP.  For his given example, this answer is much clearer than a regex based solution, so does it really warrant the down vote, or are you being a little overzealous?

Comment: I don't feel it's useful in the context of his question. Possibly I'm being overzealous; my downvote is locked, but if you want to edit your answer slightly I should be able to remove it.

Comment: @AdrianWragg: you don't have to remove it if you think it's justified (I don't really care either way and I'm not at all offended), but I think for the context of his question this answer solves it absolutely perfectly.  What you describe in your earlier comment is a variation of his problem that is a different context, based on speculation (ie "this doesn't solve any problem beyond the scope of the question body").  Arguably, you may have a point but it's really up to the OP to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following regexp:

```
http\:\/\/[\w\.]+\:\d+\/\w+\/
```

Answer (score 0):

This one should do pretty well

```
http:\/\/[\w\.]+\:\d+\/\w+\/
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

Javascript

```
function myBase(url, baseString) {
    if (url && baseString) {
        var array = url.split(new RegExp("\\b" + baseString + "\\b"));

        if (array.length === 2) {
            return array[0] + baseString + "/";
        }
    }

    return null;
}

var testUrl = "http://xxxxx.yyyy.xxxxx.com:14567/yx/someother/foldername/index.html",
    testBase = "yx";

console.log(myBase(testUrl, testBase))
```

;

Output

```
http://xxxxx.yyyy.xxxxx.com:14567/yx/
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/AdpWM/)